# Adapting Rhydars into Carnivores

Tags: biology

Yep, that's right, another [Rhydar](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/216870/explaining-an-echolocating-rhino) question. This one features yet another unusual trait of Rhydars: **they are carnivorous, more or less.** That's right, if you enter a Rhydar's territory, they won't just attack you for the heck of it, they can, will, and plan to **eat you!**

This may have evolved naturally; herbivores like deer can and do scavenge carcasses, and since Rhydar are naturally violent creatures, they should end up with lots of carcasses to scavenge. I say 'more or less' because I'm perfectly willing to settle for them being omnivorous as long as they can act like predators. **So far, it looks like Rhydars becoming omnivorous, or even carnivorous, isn't much of a stretch.**

**So, then my question is:** how would they adapt as they become more predatory? Claws are unlikely, fangs are likely, but what else? How would echolocating rhinos adapt for a more carnivorous lifestyle? Strong jaws, tusks perhaps? A longer tail to aid in maneuvering?

Comment: Is there supposed to be a link to https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/216870/explaining-an-echolocating-rhino?

Comment: @IchthysKing: yeah, thanks for pointing that out!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### A weaponized body with spikes and a horn as a hammer!

Your question was a bit vague but I believe this is the most suitable body plan for violence. Rhydars ram into their prey which means the bulk of their natural weapons should be in front of their body. Things like spikes on their shoulders would make their attacks that much deadlier. Spikes are pretty much the best thing for penetrating flesh. The longer the spike the deeper the wound. However longer spikes means more brittle and since Rhydars ram blindly into things that would be bad. Shorter stubbier spikes would be ideal.

To compliment the spikes the horn of the Rhydar could be used like a hammer to deliver blunt blows against tougher armoured enemies. Things that can't be killed with spikes like knights or rude rocks and boulders. There would be two methods of using this weapon. First by ramming straight into its prey. Secondly in close quarters by lifting their head and standing on their hind legs and slamming down their head. Broken bones guaranteed.

But I think their most powerful weapon has to be intimidation!

Comment: Very good, my question _was_ a bit too vague, so this thoughtful answer is much appreciated!